# Instead of generating PDF, it displays the HTML page on the browser

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, mpdf

I am generating a pdf using mpdf. It actually converts a HTML file into pdf. The HTML file gets filled up by some data. 
The codes in the controller are :

```
$pdfFilePath = APPPATH.'invoice/firstinvoice1901.pdf';

        //load mPDF library
        $this->load->library('m_pdf');
        $html = $this->load->view('admin/payments/viewinvoice',$this->data,true);

       //generate the PDF from the given html
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

        //save it on server.
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath,"F");
```

Now after running the codes, instead of generating a pdf, it fills up the html page and displays this page on the browser.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: try "D" parameter to download the file:
`$this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath,"D");`

Comment: I tried with "D", but it is not working either.

Comment: i guess this has something to do with CIs output class - after your line `$this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath,"F");` add a `die();` and try it again

Comment: refere here 
https://arjunphp.com/generating-a-pdf-in-codeigniter-using-mpdf/
https://davidsimpson.me/2013/05/19/using-mpdf-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

1. By using the inbuilt method of MPDF library

> $mpdf->Output('MyPDF.pdf', 'D');

Or

2. You can do it by force download method.

   > ```
   >  $filename = "fileName.pdf";
   >    if (file_exists($filename)) {
   >       header('Content-type: application/force-download');
   >       header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
   >       readfile($filename);
   >     }
   > ```